# possible concurrent write of *same* value to an integer. Do I need an atomic variable?

Tags: c++, concurrency, atomic

I want to introduce an optimization into some legacy code. The optimization boils down to the following simple example:

```
class Foo{
        static int m_count;   // allocated and initialized to -1 to indicate it's uninitialized.
        void fun(){
            if (m_count ==-1)
                m_count = execute_db_call(); // return a val > 0.
            if (m_count == 1) {
                 // call special == 1 optimized code.
            } else {
                 // call expensive code.
            }
       }
   }
```

1. `fun()` will be called millions of times on hundreds of threads, all running concurrently on a 256 core server.
2. `execute_db_call` is expensive, and the return value is constant for the lifetime of the application.

Do I need or want to make `m_count` atomic?  In the worst case multiple threads might call `execute_db_call`, and get the same value, and then write this value to the same location in memory.  Is that a race condition even when both threads attempt to write the same integer value?

If I did make the member atomic, what kind of performance overhead am I looking at for the subsequent read only behavior?

Comment: Where exactly is the value of `m_count` going to be changed?

Comment: oops, modified the sample

Comment: *"Is that a race condition even when both threads attempt to write the same integer value?"* - Uhm, yes. Just because you presume, that this kind of undefined behavior is harmless, doesn't make it defined behavior. Or harmless. You certainly need an atomic (and likely more elaborate synchronization for your shared resource; there's another data race between calling `execute_db_call` and assigning the return value).

Comment: @IINspectable  I don't think I agree about the second race.  execute_db_call must always return the same value.  With atomic int, the worst case is I execute some unecessary DB calls, and reassign the count... but I'll always get the same count.   So behavior will always be okay.   Is my reasoning false?

Comment: *"Is my reasoning false?"* - Yes. If it were correct, the value returned from `execute_db_call` would not ever change. And that's just the high-level, almost-can-be-dealt-with issue. You don't appear to appreciate, that *plausibility* is a poor teacher, when it comes to determining *guarantees*.

Comment: The value returned by "execute_db_call" will never change for the lifetime of the program, as I stated in item 2.

Answer (score 1):

Per standard §1.10/21:

> The execution of a program contains a data race if it contains two conflicting actions in different threads, at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other. Any such data race results in undefined behavior.

It looks like your code matches this definition, so you will get UB. Now, even assuming your application will never crush (oh well...) you might get unnecessary `execute_db_call` calls, and you have explicitly stated that "*execute_db_call is expensive*", so it's still bad.

Comment: Sort of agreed.  The application will run a long time, and if the db calls happens three or four times at startup, it will be unmeasureable.  On the other hand if the atomic integer checks causes a bottleneck b/c 128 cores are all checking at the same time, thousands of times per second, that could be bad.

Comment: r.e. the standard citation, I guess my question boils down to:  does two thread simultaneously writing the same value to the same location in memory qualify as a *conflicting* action?

Comment: @Spacemoose, of course it does (1.10/4): _"Two expression evaluations conflict if one of them modifies a memory location (1.7) and the other one
accesses or modifies the same memory location."_ The fact that they attempt to write the same value does not affect this definition.

Comment: Well, okay, that's clearly correct -- but do you really find it to be an "of course"?   I can understand and explain how a problem will occur if two threads simultaneously write different values to an integer, but I can't explain how a problem will occur if they attempt to write the same value.

Comment: @SpaceMoose There are problems if the data type is smaller than the architecture's native atomic unit and a nearby variable changes. Consider what happens if `m_count` is a bitfield.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what properties, if any, you need to be assured `m_count` has after the process has completed, or whether it matters what its value happens to be at any stage during the processing. In the absence of such properties, you might as well not assign it a value at all. If you do need the value of `m_count` to be anything other than undefined at any point in your processing, you *assuredly* must use synchronization to ensure that the sequence of actions taken in relation to that variable remains consistent.

If `m_count` is only written in the -1 case, and the variable is shared by all threads, you would be vastly better off moving that initialization outside of the parallel part of your program. You could thus eliminate any data races and avoid unnecessarily calling you expensive function.